# The body might complete normally causing null to be returned but the return type is a potentially non nullable type

Tags: flutter

What did I do wrong?

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please put code in your question, not a screenshot of your code.

Comment: You forgot the `return` keyword on default.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `buildHome()` in your default case like the other cases.